# Compact set and continue function

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, convergence-divergence, continuity, compactness

Let $f : \mathbb R \times \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ be a continuous function and $I \subset \mathbb R$ a closed interval.

$$E = \{(x, (y_1, y_2)) \in I \times \mathbb R^2 : f(x, (y_1, y_2)) = C\}$$
for a certain constant $C \in \mathbb R$.

Is $E$ compact or what are the other conditions for $E$ to be a compact set?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write $E$ as

$$E=f^{-1}[\{C\}]\cap(I\times\Bbb R^2)\;,$$

which makes it clear that $E$ is a closed subset of $\Bbb R^3$; thus, $E$ is compact if and only if it is bounded in $\Bbb R^3$.

Comment: Why is it "clearly" closed? :/

Comment: @trgjkyfojn: $\{C\}$ is a closed subset of $\Bbb R$, and $f$ is a continuous function, so $f^{-1}[\{C\}]$ is closed in $\Bbb R^3$. This is a general fact about continuous functions: inverse images of closed sets are closed. $I\times\Bbb R^2$ is a closed subset of $\Bbb R^3$, because it is the Cartesian product of closed sets. Finally, the intersection of two closed sets is closed.

Comment: Is it clear that $x$ is bounded (because $x \in I$ which is a closed interval)
So if I prove that $(y_1, y_2)$ is bounded in $\mathbb R^2$, $E$ is compact?

Comment: @trgjkyfojn: No; nothing in the hypotheses implies that $E$ is bounded. It’s entirely possible, for instance, that there is some $x_0\in I$ such that $\{x_0\}\times\Bbb R^2\subseteq E$, i.e., such that $f(x_0,\langle y_0,y_1\rangle)=C$ for every $\langle y_0,y_1\rangle\in\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: Because I have proved in another exercise that for $f(x, Y) = C$, $Y$ has to be bounded in $\mathbb R^2$ ($Y = (y_1, y_2)$). So I wonder if it is clear that for all $x \in I$, $x$ is bounded because $x < \max I$.

Comment: @trgjkyfojn: From that it is possible to prove that $E$ is bounded and therefore compact, but it’s not trivial and does take some work.

Answer (score 0):

In general, no, it is not compact. If, say, $f$ is the constant function $C$, then $E=I\times\Bbb R^2$.

However, if $f$ is a [proper map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_map), then, yes, $E$ will be compact.